# Read .env variables in crontab

Tags: bash, cron, environment-variables

I have a crontab and .env file. And I want to reach .env variables from crontab. Is it possible?

.env

```
variable1=value1
variable2=value2
```

crontab

```
2 11 * * * curl -Ssi -X POST -u 'value1:value2' https://example.com...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to create a script that reads you .env file an runs the command, like this:

```
#!/bash
# This is /my_path/my_script.sh file,
# do not forget to set executable permission by chmod

# Reading vars
. /my_path/my_env.env
# Calling the command
curl -Ssi -X POST -u "${variable1}:${variable2}" https://example.com...
```

and your crontab line will be like this:

```
2 11 * * * /my_path/my_script.sh
```

or alternatively in not so readable manner, directly in the crontab:

```
2 11 * * * . /my_path/my_env.env; curl -Ssi -X POST -u "${variable1}:${variable2}" https://example.com...
```

Comment: First choice is not possible because I have tons of cron row. I couldn't write a script file for each of them. Second option looks like a good option for now.

Answer (score 1):

Source your `.env` file within cron, and I assume you mean `$variable1:$variable2`.

```
2 11 * * * . /path/to/.env; curl -Ssi -X POST -u "$variable1:$variable2" https://example.com...
```